# How to add Multiple animated arrow icon on single line string in open layers

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

We are trying to add multiple arrow icon on single line string in this code but we are not able to add.
so how we add multiple animated arrow icon on this code we also add image of your reference.

[Click Here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJNS2.png)

I want when we click start button then add one arrow icon on line string and when we click again start button then add same new arrow icon on these line string

```
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import LineString from 'ol/geom/LineString';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import Polyline from 'ol/format/Polyline';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {Icon, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {getVectorContext} from 'ol/render';

const center = [-5639523.95, -3501274.52];
const map = new Map({
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 19,
  }),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
});

// The polyline string is read from a JSON similiar to those returned
// by directions APIs such as Openrouteservice and Mapbox.
fetch('data/polyline/route.json').then(function (response) {
  response.json().then(function (result) {
    const polyline = result.routes[0].geometry;

    const route = new Polyline({
      factor: 1e6,
    }).readGeometry(polyline, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    });

    const routeFeature = new Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route,
    });
    const startMarker = new Feature({
      type: 'icon',
      geometry: new Point(route.getFirstCoordinate()),
    });
    const endMarker = new Feature({
      type: 'icon',
      geometry: new Point(route.getLastCoordinate()),
    });
    const position = startMarker.getGeometry().clone();
    const geoMarker = new Feature({
      type: 'geoMarker',
      geometry: position,
    });

    const styles = {
      route: new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          width: 6,
          color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8],
        }),
      }),
      icon: new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: 'data/icon.png',
        }),
      }),
      geoMarker: new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          src:
            'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-color-round/3/19-32.png',
          rotation: getAngleAt(route, 0) + Math.PI / 2,
        }),
      }),
    };

    const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        features: [routeFeature, geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker],
      }),
      style: function (feature) {
        return styles[feature.get('type')];
      },
    });

    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

    const speedInput = document.getElementById('speed');
    const startButton = document.getElementById('start-animation');
    let animating = false;
    let distance = 0;
    let lastTime;

    function getAngleAt(lineString, distance) {
      const length = lineString.getLength();
      const coordinates = lineString.getCoordinates();
      for (let i = 1, len = coordinates.length; i <= len; ++i) {
        if (
          new LineString(coordinates.slice(0, i)).getLength() >=
          length * distance
        ) {
          return -Math.atan2(
            coordinates[i][1] - coordinates[i - 1][1],
            coordinates[i][0] - coordinates[i - 1][0]
          );
        }
      }
    }

    function moveFeature(event) {
      const speed = Number(speedInput.value);
      const time = event.frameState.time;
      const elapsedTime = time - lastTime;
      distance = (distance + (speed * elapsedTime) / 1e6) % 2;
      lastTime = time;
      const lineDistance = distance > 1 ? 2 - distance : distance;
      const direction = distance > 1 ? -Math.PI / 2 : Math.PI / 2;
      const currentCoordinate = route.getCoordinateAt(lineDistance);
      const angle = getAngleAt(route, lineDistance) + direction;
      styles.geoMarker.getImage().setRotation(angle);
      position.setCoordinates(currentCoordinate);
      const vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);
      vectorContext.setStyle(styles.geoMarker);
      vectorContext.drawGeometry(position);
      // tell OpenLayers to continue the postrender animation
      map.render();
    }

    function startAnimation() {
      animating = true;
      lastTime = Date.now();
      startButton.textContent = 'Stop Animation';
      vectorLayer.on('postrender', moveFeature);
      // hide geoMarker and trigger map render through change event
      geoMarker.setGeometry(null);
    }

    function stopAnimation() {
      animating = false;
      startButton.textContent = 'Start Animation';

      // Keep marker at current animation position
      geoMarker.setGeometry(position);
      vectorLayer.un('postrender', moveFeature);
    }

    startButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (animating) {
        stopAnimation();
      } else {
        startAnimation();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Marker Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ol/ol.css">
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <label for="speed">
      speed:&nbsp;
      <input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="60">
    </label>
    <button id="start-animation">Start Animation</button>
    <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep@1.0.6/dist/elm-pep.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

We try this code in this code we are not able to add multiple icon on line string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeat for as many arrows as you need on the linestring

```
function moveFeature(event) {
  const speed = Number(speedInput.value);
  const time = event.frameState.time;
  const elapsedTime = time - lastTime;
  distance = (distance + (speed * elapsedTime) / 1e6) % 2;
  lastTime = time;
  for (let i = 0; i < arrows; ++i) {
    const arrowDistance = (distance + (2 * i) / arrows) % 2;
    const lineDistance = arrowDistance > 1 ? 2 - arrowDistance : arrowDistance;
    const direction = arrowDistance > 1 ? -Math.PI / 2 : Math.PI / 2;
    const currentCoordinate = route.getCoordinateAt(lineDistance);
    const angle = getAngleAt(route, lineDistance) + direction;
    styles.geoMarker.getImage().setRotation(angle);
    position.setCoordinates(currentCoordinate);
    const vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);
    vectorContext.setStyle(styles.geoMarker);
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(position);
  }
  // tell OpenLayers to continue the postrender animation
  map.render();
}
```

For arrows going forward and reverse calculate the interval based on 2 times the length

```
const arrowDistance = (distance + (2 * i) / arrows) % 2;
```

For one way traffic use a single length

```
const arrowDistance = (distance +  i / arrows) % 1;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/feature-move-animation-forked-w7dzx3

Comment: Thank you Mike for your respond, but I want when we click start button then add one animated arrow icon on line string and when we click again start button then add new animated arrow icon on these line string and keep running previous arrow .

Answer (score 0):

check out this answer which help me to solve my problem  :-
https://answersyouarefinding.blogspot.com/2023/01/how-to-add-multiple-animated-arrow-icon.html

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but we want in open layers not in html.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).